# Cannot find control with path: 'members -> 0 ->

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

So I'm trying to add dynamic form, its getting added but I am getting console error:

```
Cannot find control with path: 'members -> 0 -> '
```

so please help me to resolve the issue. so the below are html and ts files. So when trying load the page in constructor adding default fields and on add click adding dynamic form to formarray

```
<form [formGroup]="memberDetails">
        <div formArrayName="members" *ngFor="let item of memberDetails.get('members').controls; let i=index;">
                <div  class="form-row memberform-container" [formGroupName]="i" >
                    <!-- {{currentFormIndex}} -->
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                            <label for="firstname">First Name <em class="required">*</em></label>
                            <input type="text" [formControlName] ="firstname" class="form-control" id="firstname">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                            <label for="middlename">Middle Name</label>
                            <input type="text" formControlName ="middlename" class="form-control" id="middlename">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                            <label for="lastname">Last Name <em class="required">*</em></label>
                            <input type="text" formControlName ="lastname" class="form-control" id="lastname">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                            <label for="suffix">Suffix</label>
                            <select formControlName ="suffix" id="suffix" class="form-control">
                                <option value ="">Select</option>
                                <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
                                <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                            <label for="dob">Date of Birth <em class="required">*</em></label>
                            <!-- <form class="form-inline"> -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input formControlName ="dob" class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp"
                                            ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" [placement]="placement"
                                            [positionTarget]="buttonEl">
                                        <div class="input-group-append">
                                            <button #buttonEl class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" (click)="d.toggle()"
                                                type="button"></button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <!-- </form> -->
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                            <label for="dob">Gender <em class="required">*</em></label>
                            <div class="row ml-0">
                                        <button type="button" (click)="save()" class="btn" style="border: 1px solid lightgray; border-radius:0;">Male</button>
                                        <button type="button" (click)="save()" class="btn" style="border: 1px solid lightgray;border-radius:0;">Female</button>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                                <label for="dob">Is primary Applicant applying for health coverage? (Choose "Yes" if he or she wants to apply for a private
                                        health plan or Medicaid/Maryland Childern's Health Program, even if he or she is already enrolled through Maryland Health Connection.)<em class="required">*</em></label>
                                <div class="row ml-0">
                                            <button type="button" (click)="save()" class="btn" style="border: 1px solid lightgray; border-radius:0;">Yes</button>
                                            <button type="button" (click)="save()" class="btn" style="border: 1px solid lightgray;border-radius:0;">No</button>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <!-- <custom-radio-button></custom-radio-button> -->
                    </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

ts file

```
//in constructor add default form array zero
this.memberDetails = this.fb.group({
    members: this.fb.array([this.createFormContorls()])
});   
get detailsArray(): FormArray {
    return this.memberDetails.get('members') as FormArray;
}
//add dynamic form to memeber array
addMember() {
    this.memberDetails = this.currentPageData['membersForm'];
    this.detailsArray.push(this.createFormContorls());
    this.store.dispatch(new TestActions.GetFormData(this.memberDetails));
    this.store.select('data').subscribe(data => {
      this.memberDetails = data['membersForm'];
      this.currentFormIndex = this.detailsArray.length -1;
    });
  }
createFormContorls() {
return this.fb.group({
  firstname: new FormControl(''),
  middlename: new FormControl(''),
  lastname: new FormControl(''),
  suffix: new FormControl(''),
  dob: new FormControl('')
}); }
```

Comment: Can you also share `createFormContorls` method?

Comment: added the function @yurzui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just update this line :

```
<input type="text" [formControlName] ="firstname" class="form-control" id="firstname">
```

to

```
<input type="text" formControlName ="firstname" class="form-control" id="firstname">
```

Explanation :
The brackets, [], tell Angular to evaluate the template expression which means that it will looks for a variable/function with this name.
If you want to keep this syntax you need to declare a variable named firstname with firstname as value, inside your ts :

```
...
firstname = firstname ;
...
```